# How to enable boolean fields?

Tags: 7, entities

I installed the minimal setup when installing Drupal, and I want a boolean field in one of my Content Types. But this is not enabled. I found this [Boolean module](https://www.drupal.org/project/boolean), but it only has 859 installs (as of 6th Jan, 2014), so I doubt I need to install that. So how can I enable 'Boolean' as one of the field types?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to enable the [List](https://www.drupal.org/documentation/modules/list) module, which also gives you the List, List (numeric) and List (text) field types.